# How to return/print matches on a string in RegEx in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: regex, flutter, parsing, dart

I want to return a pattern through regEx in flutter every time it' found, I tested using the Regex operation it worked on the same string, returning the match after that included match 'text:' to '}' letters, but it does not print the matches in the flutter application.

The code I am using:

```
String myString = '{boundingBox: 150,39,48,25, text: PM},';
RegExp exp = RegExp(r"text:(.+?(?=}))");
print("allMatches : "+exp.allMatches(myString).toString());
```

The output print statement is printing `I/flutter ( 5287): allMatches : (Instance of '_RegExpMatch', Instance of '_RegExpMatch')` 
instead of `text: PM`

Following is the screenshot of how it is parsing on regexr.com

[image]

Comment: I think you put backslash at the start of your regex by mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but still not meaningful output, the current output after removing slash : allMatches : (Instance of '_RegExpMatch', Instance of '_RegExpMatch')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a non greedy match with a lookahead, I would suggest using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching any char except `}` in capture group 1, and match the `}` after the group to prevent some backtracking.

```
\b(text:[^}]+)}
```

You can loop the result from [allMatches](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/RegExp/allMatches.html) and print group 1:

```
String myString = '{boundingBox: 150,39,48,25, text: PM},';
RegExp exp = RegExp(r"\b(text:[^}]+)}");
for (var m in exp.allMatches(myString)) {
    print(m[1]);    
}
```

Output

```
text: PM
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use map method to retrieve the string from the matches:

```
String myString = '{boundingBox: 150,39,48,25, text: PM},';
RegExp exp = RegExp(r"text:(.+?(?=}))");

final matches = exp.allMatches(myString).map((m) => m.group(0)).toString();

print("allMatches : $matches");
```